Pandoc HTML Reader , Read <title> tag , as a pandoc Object Header?
I am doing a Custom Parser for different documentation stored in .html .
I am interested on parsing the <title> tag of the documents, but it seems that the default pandoc Reader for HTML doesn't parse such a tag.
Having this simple example of input.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Research Article</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Introduction</h1>
  <p>This is the introduction to my research article.</p>
</body>
</html>

Doing pandoc input.html -t native
I get
[ Header
    1 ( "introduction" , [] , [] ) [ Str "Introduction" ]
, Para
    [ Str "This"
    , Space
    , Str "is"
    , Space
    , Str "the"
    , Space
    , Str "introduction"
    , Space
    , Str "to"
    , Space
    , Str "my"
    , Space
    , Str "research"
    , Space
    , Str "article."
    ]
]

So I see the <title> tag is not read by default.
Is there a way to implement a Custom Reader , with lua syntax , to recognise such a tag? And read it as a Pandoc Object Header ?

Pandoc actually does parse the title, but you're missing the -s or --standalone flag. Try:
pandoc -f html -t native -s

